# Excel formula to sum as long as

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to find a formula to calculate the balance of a column until a negative value is found. After the negative value is found, the balance must be calculated again until the next negative value. Basically tracking what you spent, except it only shows a value when you sold something. Anybody have an idea if this is possible to do in MS excel? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. So, what have you [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I'm confused about your -18 + 20. It doesn't seem to follow the pattern - i.e. where does the 20 come from?

Comment: @compor I've managed getting the balance to show the right result until José, although the problems comes up after because it needs to ignore the balances that came before José and start with the new ones that follow up

Comment: @Carol It comes from Miguel. Miguel bought 4 apples for 5$/apple. Afterwards 5 apples from oliver were sold and 3 apples from antonio for 6$ each, that should be subtracted from the 20$ that miguel spent (the names dont really play a role, could be the same one everywhere, it's about the balance). Every time something gets sold it has to be subtracted from all the previous buys till the last sold.

Comment: Yes, but you are adding in Miguel's 20 twice.  In line 6 and again in line 7

Comment: @RonRosenfeld exactly. I probably made a bad example for the task I wanna do. Imagine it was always the same person, as he just wanted to find out how much he made selling those apples for different prices. He bought them for 5$/apple and sold 5 of them for 6$ aswell as other 3 of them for 6$ to someone else. That's why there's 20 twice

Comment: So Miguel purchased 4 apples for $5 each.  Then, out of those 4 apples, he sold 5 apples to Oliver for $6, and another 3 to Antonio for $6.  I love that business model :-)

Comment: On a more serious note, develop a realistic example to use.  Then describe exactly what you want to be showing in the `Balance` column; what you have tried and where the problem lies.  Examples that don't reflect your real data are likely to lead to solutions that don't apply to your real data.

Comment: @compor I've edited the image/example to make more sense. Hope you can help!

Comment: @Carol I've edited the image/example to make more sense. Hope you can help!

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I've edited the image/example to make more sense. Hope you can help!

Comment: How are you calculating those results?  What is the logic behind the results in E6 and E7?  Why not just calculate a running balance?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld it's the profit he made by selling those apples. He bought 25 for 5$. Sold 5 of those 25 for 6$, so he made 1$ with each apple adding up to 5$ profit. Same for the 19$. The point is to calculate the profit each time something was sold out of the price it was bought with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Now I get your question. I think the following will do the trick. The results exactly match your example.

```
// In these cells only
F2: =MAX(0,B2*C2)
G2: =MAX(0,B2)+MIN(0,B2)

// In these cells, then copy down
E3: =IF(B3<0,D3-(F2-F3),"")
F3: =F2+MAX(0,B3*C3)+IF(G2=0,0,MIN(0,B3*F2/G2))
G3: =G2+MAX(0,B3)+MIN(0,B3)
```

I would note a couple of things about this:

1) You might consider changing the names of your columns to trans, quan, $ per, $ ttl, $ gp, and name the 2 columns I am adding $ inv and inv.
2) This is using the average cost of inventory, recalculated with each transaction, not LIFO or FIFO.
3) If entries get out of order such that quan goes negative, I think this solution will fail. In any case, that might be an error you'd want to notice.
4) FYI, the "IF(G2=0" part of F3 is only there to avoid a divide by 0 error when G2 (inventory) is 0. I could have done this other ways, of course. It works.
5) I've left E2 blank on the assumption that you can't sell as you've not bought.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I appreciate you taking the time for it. It worked perfectly as I needed it to! Cheers

Comment: I still have one question though. What formula can be used to get the total profit? I get as far as getting the sum() for all the profit but I also have to add the last "$ inv" cell value to receive the complete profit made

Comment: By total profit, I assume you mean cumulative profit on all sales? If you only wanted this to display when a sale is made, in cell H2 (and copied down):  =IF(E2="","",SUM(E$2:E2))

Comment: Didnt mean it like that. I basically wanna achieve a cell that contains the total profit made, which is made out of every single profit from a sale added together (easy to calculate, only a sum() function needed) aswell as the amount that was in the last "$ inv" cell as that is also a part of the profit made, if you cash out the whole sum you cant just calculate the profit made with it but also the rest

Comment: You can just add the $inv balance to the same formula: =IF(E2="","",SUM(E$2:E2)+F2) // I think the answer may already be what you want, however, as the prior =IF(E2="","",SUM(E$2:E2)) is calculating GP only on items sold (using average cost), leaving cost of unsold items in $ inv. Thus, $ inv has not be expensed in this SS via a reduction to $ GP. What you may be getting at is essentially a liquidation value, GP to date plus $ inv. If so, this new version of the formula should work. // Am I on the right track?

Comment: Yes the formula would be correct but it cant be placed in one single cell as it wont be dragged down to always match the latest $ inv etc. It is a static cell so the formula would need to always fetch the latest $ inv amount.

Comment: Indeed but it is not the result I'm trying to achieve. It should be in a single cell.

Comment: If you are looking to have a single cell display the sum of the most recent $ inv and all $ GP to date, in any unused cell put: =SUM(E:E)+LOOKUP(2,1/(F:F<>""),F:F) || The =SUM(E:E) part obviously sums all $GP, while the rest adds the value of the last non-empty cell in column F ($ inv).

Comment: terrific! That did the job! Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to add 2 additional columns, which could be hidden or on another sheet, then (here assuming adding columns F2 and G2 added at the right):

```
In Cell E2: =IF(B2<0,G2,"")  
In Cell F2: =B2*C2  
In Cell G2: =SUM(F$2:F2)
```

Copy these down and, assuming I understand your question correctly, you'll get the results you desire.

Comment: This doesn't give the OP the results in their example? Am I missing something?

Comment: @carol The question wasn't exactly clear to me. The image included had numbers in balance that didn't match the question as I understood it. The follow up Q&A indicated I was not alone, with one answer clarifying; "I've managed getting the balance to show the right result until José." I can't see "Jose" in the image, which I'm guessing is cut off at the right, thus this still didn't clarify for me, but it indicated that the balance may not be as desired. Looking at the question, I gave the solution for one of 2 possibilities, that of displaying the running balance upon occurrence of a sale.

Comment: I agree it's very confusing. I worked it out by a bit of trial and error that what the OP wants is the profit on each sale based on the last buy price.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem you've got with this is working out the ranges to check for the balance calculation. This won't work if the next row in your table is a 'sell' while you've still got one 'apple' left from the previous purchase. If you want to do anything more convoluted you should use VBA.

Others will probably have an easier way to work out the ranges; I did it in a rather convoluted way and don't have time to optimise them.

In column F there's an array formula to calculate the last row in the range of 'buys' relevant to that 'sell'.

```
=IF($B2>=0,"",LARGE(IF($B$2:$B2>0,ROW($A$2:$A2)),1))
```

In column G there's a normal formula to capture the row number of the first row in the range.

```
=IF(ROW()=2,ROW(),IF(B2>0,IF(B1<0,ROW(),""),""))
```

In column H, convert this to be stored in the relevant 'sell' row using an array formula:

```
=IF($B2>=0,"",LARGE(IF($G$2:$G2>0,$G$2:G2),1))
```

In column E, balance, use these calculated row range references in an INDIRECT statement to calculate the balance.

```
=IF(B2>0,"",(C2*-(B2))-(-(B2)*(SUMPRODUCT(INDIRECT("B"&H2&":B"&F2),INDIRECT("C"&H2&":C"&F2)/SUM(INDIRECT("B"&H2&":B"&F2))))))
```

Note that INDIRECT uses a string to reference cells and ranges and if you move cells or ranges you will have to manually change the INDIRECT string to reference the correct cells.

Comment: Is it only doable via VBA? You're right, my problem is finding the range of cells that need to be checked for the balance. My goal is to make a formula that only needs to be dragged down to apply to every cell, no matter if an "apple" is left or not. Why not keep some to himself, maybe he's hungry :)

Comment: These formulas will work if you want to ignore any extra apples. But they won't check if you're selling more apples than you have. They won't be able to calculate if part of a sale comes from one bunch of apple sales and part from another. Using these formulas I got the results you had in your balance column but this is only for your example and I can't guarantee it'll work for other circumstances. If it was me, I'd probably write a VBA User Defined Function (UDF).

Answer (score 0):

Responding to @carol, and looking at the Q&A again, specifically where you say " although the problems comes up after because it needs to ignore the balances that came before José and start with the new ones that follow up," I realize that you may be looking to instead display the balance of all sales receipts and purchases since the last sale. If so:

```
In Cell G2: =F2
```

Do not copy down the above. Do copy down those below.

```
In Cell E2: =IF(B2<0,G2,"")  
In Cell F2: =B2*C2  
In Cell G3: =IF(B2<0,F3,F3+G2)
```

Comment: I dont think you really understood the task I want to achieve. The picture shows the balance column, which has the results in it that I want to achieve with a global formula.

Comment: I'm lost on your balance calc. E4 seems to be the balance of earned versus paid since the last sale, essentially a gross profit since last sale, while E6 and E7 seem to be the inventory balance of amounts bought and sold. Whatever you are trying to get at, I think you are going to need another column somewhere to calculate a running balance.

Comment: actually E4 is also an inventory balance of amounts bought and sold, as you mentioned for E6 and E7. I made 4$ win with the first buy of 2 apples compared to when I sold them and I made 5$ win with the second buy of 5 apples compared to when I sold them for 7$ each. I'd just like to have one formula, doesnt really matter if it's with an additional column, that I can just drag down and it'll calculate automatically all buys and sells.

Comment: I posted a new answer to the question that I think I finally understand correctly. I've left the other answers as they might be useful to others with different scenarios.